# Design Pinterest and G+ button on website

Tags: html, css, google-plus, pinterest

How can we customize design of pinterest and G+ button added on website for sharing purpose? I've added following two button with this code but I need to design these buttons according to other buttons on website.

```
<a class="pin" data-pin-do="buttonPin" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo base_url(); ?>Product/<?php echo $result->itemId; ?>&media=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/17/34/8e/17348e163a3212c06e61c41c4b22b87a.jpg&description=<?php echo urlencode($result->title); ?>" ><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>


<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="none" data-href="http://bafwebsite.localhost/Product/720"></div>
```

As you can see g+ button is in div, can i make it just like pinterest inside anchor tag and use fa icons??

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the [Google+ Share Link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#share-link)

The default snippet is this:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

But you could pretty easily make it the same as your existing Pinterest snippet.

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo base_url(); ?>Product/<?php echo $result->itemId; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-google-plus-official"></i></a>
```